# Change Android volume bar

Tags: android, instagram, volume

When you are in an Instagram story, and you decide to raise or lower the volume, this custom bar appears

[image: Volume bar on Instagram app]

Instead, the normal volume bar looks like this

[image: Default volume bar on my Android phone]

I've researched ways to do it, but haven't found any.

How do I make this effect in Android Studio?

PD: I want to make this effect only when a person is using my application NOT to change the volume bar on  the Android system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Key Event to find control of volume up and down button like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And then create a custom seek bar and control the seek bar progress with the button control.
Hope it works.

Comment: A nice trick is to use (and allow) the app as an overlay and customize your volume bar globally.